# Concatenation of column values on bases of confirmation_number

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have below two tables

Work_Request table

```
ASSIGNED_TO_USER_ID NUMBER (22,10)  
COMPANY_ID  NUMBER (5)  
COMPLETE_DATE   DATE    
CORP_ID CHAR (2 Byte)   
CREATE_DATE DATE    
CREATE_USER_ID  NUMBER (22,10)  
FINANCIAL_INSTITUTION_ID    CHAR (2 Byte)   
MODIFY_DATE DATE    
MODIFY_USER_ID  NUMBER (22,10)  
STATUS_ID   INTEGER 
TOKEN_NUMBER    VARCHAR2 (16 Byte)  
WORK_REQUEST_DESC   VARCHAR2 (500 Byte) 
WORK_REQUEST_DETAILS    CLOB    
WORK_REQUEST_ID VARCHAR2 (36 Byte)  
WORK_REQUEST_NUMBER VARCHAR2 (25 Byte)  
WORK_REQUEST_TYPE_ID    VARCHAR2 (36 Byte)
```

Work_Request_Note table

```
CREATE_DATE DATE    
CREATE_USER_ID  NUMBER (22,10)  
NOTE_TEXT   VARCHAR2 (4000 Byte)    
WORK_REQUEST_ID VARCHAR2 (36 Byte)  
WORK_REQUEST_NOTE_ID    VARCHAR2 (36 Byte)
```

I got script from you where i have a column in work_request table name as Notes which need to combine on basis of
same Confirmation# column.You gave me query which concatenated the Notes for same Confirmation# and joining with work_request_note.Output concatenated the Notes for each confirmation# in ascending order but we need to concatenate these Notes for each Confirmation in ascending order.....Notes can merge by Confrimation# column and order in descending by work_request_note.create_date                                                                                         here is my query which is merging Notes on basis of confirmation# in ascending oreder

I have tried below script :

```
WITH CombinedNotes AS (
       SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN Lpad(DBMS_LOB.SubStr(work_request_details, 
                    DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"', DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"'), 1) - (DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')), 
                    DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')
                ), 5, 0) = '0Text'
                THEN Lpad(TO_CHAR(COMPANY.COMPANY_ID), 5, 0)
            ELSE Lpad(DBMS_LOB.SubStr(work_request_details, 
                    DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"', DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"'), 1) - (DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')), 
                    DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')
                ), 5, 0)
        END AS "COMPANY NUMBER",
        COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME AS "COMPANY NAME",
        work_request_number AS "Confirmation #",
        work_request_type.WORK_REQUEST_TYPE_NAME AS "Request Type",
        --work_request.WORK_REQUEST_DESC AS "Detail Description",
        regexp_replace(work_request.WORK_REQUEST_DESC, '<.+?>') "Detail Description",
        TO_CHAR(work_request.CREATE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS "Date Submitted",
        TO_CHAR(work_request.COMPLETE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS "Date Completed",
        ROUND(TO_NUMBER(work_request.COMPLETE_DATE - work_request.CREATE_DATE)) AS "Days to Complete",
        CMS_USER.USER_NAME AS "Assigned To Id",
        CMS_USER.USER_DESCRIPTION AS "Assigned To NAME",
        deleted_cms_user.USER_NAME AS "Deleted Assigned To ID",
        deleted_cms_user.USER_DESCRIPTION AS "Deleted Assigned To Name",
        CASE
            WHEN (DBMS_LOB.SubStr(work_request_details, 
                DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"', DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"IsComplaint":') + Length('"IsComplaint":'), 1) - (DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"IsComplaint":') + Length('"IsComplaint":,')),
                DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"IsComplaint":') + Length('"IsComplaint":')
            )) = 'true' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS "Is Complaint",
        CASE
            WHEN (DBMS_LOB.SubStr(work_request_details, 
                DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"', DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CallResultedInCustomerComplaint":"') + Length('"CallResultedInCustomerComplaint":"'), 1) - (DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CallResultedInCustomerComplaint":"') + Length('"CallResultedInCustomerComplaint":"')),
                DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CallResultedInCustomerComplaint":"') + Length('"CallResultedInCustomerComplaint":"')
            )) = 'Yes' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS "Results in Complaint",
        TO_CHAR(work_request_note.create_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ' ' || REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTR(work_request_note.note_text, 1, 10000), '(', ''), ')', '') || ' '  AS "Notes",
        TO_CHAR(work_request_message.create_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ' ' || REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTR(work_request_message.message_text, 1, 10000), '(', ''), ')', '') || ' '  AS "Messages",
        --SUBSTR(work_request_message.message_text, 1, 10000) AS "Messages",
        work_request_status.STATUS AS "Status",
        work_request.create_date As "Creation Date"
    FROM work_request
    LEFT JOIN work_request_note ON work_request.WORK_REQUEST_ID = work_request_note.WORK_REQUEST_ID
    LEFT JOIN work_request_message ON work_request.WORK_REQUEST_ID = work_request_message.WORK_REQUEST_ID
    LEFT JOIN work_request_type ON work_request.WORK_REQUEST_TYPE_ID = work_request_type.WORK_REQUEST_TYPE_ID
    LEFT JOIN CMS_USER ON work_request.ASSIGNED_TO_USER_ID = CMS_USER.SEQ_USER_ID
    LEFT JOIN deleted_cms_user ON work_request.ASSIGNED_TO_USER_ID = deleted_cms_user.USER_ID
    LEFT JOIN COMPANY ON work_request.company_id = company.company_id AND company.corp_ID IN ('CB', 'CC')
    LEFT JOIN work_request_status ON work_request.STATUS_ID = work_request_status.STATUS_ID
    WHERE (work_request.corp_ID IN ('CB', 'CC') OR work_request.financial_institution_id = 'CO')
        AND work_request_type.WORK_REQUEST_TYPE_NAME = 'Client Notification Exception Request'
        AND TRUNC(work_request.create_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/01/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('11/01/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        AND ((work_request.create_date > sysdate-30) AND ( work_request.STATUS_ID = 90))
        OR work_request.STATUS_ID IN (0,10)
    UNION
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN Lpad(DBMS_LOB.SubStr(work_request_details, 
                    DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"', DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"'), 1) - (DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')), 
                    DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')
                ), 5, 0) = '0Text'
                THEN Lpad(TO_CHAR(COMPANY.COMPANY_ID), 5, 0)
            ELSE Lpad(DBMS_LOB.SubStr(work_request_details, 
                    DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"', DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"'), 1) - (DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')), 
                    DBMS_LOB.InStr(work_request_details, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')
                ), 5, 0)
        END AS "COMPANY NUMBER",
        COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME AS "COMPANY NAME",
        work_request_number AS "Confirmation #",
        work_request_type.WORK_REQUEST_TYPE_NAME AS "Request Type",
        --work_request.WORK_REQUEST_DESC AS "Detail Description",
        regexp_replace(work_request.WORK_REQUEST_DESC, '<.+?>') "Detail Description",
        TO_CHAR(work_request.CREATE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS "Date Submitted",
        TO_CHAR(work_request.COMPLETE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS "Date Completed",
        ROUND(TO_NUMBER(work_request.COMPLETE_DATE - work_request.CREATE_DATE)) AS "Days to Complete",
        CMS_USER.USER_NAME AS "Assigned To Id",
        CMS_USER.USER_DESCRIPTION AS "Assigned To NAME",
        deleted_cms_user.USER_NAME AS "Deleted Assigned To ID",
        deleted_cms_user.USER_DESCRIPTION AS "Deleted Assigned To Name",
        'N' AS "Is Complaint",
        'N' AS "Results in Complaint",
        TO_CHAR(work_request_note.create_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ' ' || REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTR(work_request_note.note_text, 1, 10000), '(', ''), ')', '') || ' '  AS "Notes",
        TO_CHAR(work_request_message.create_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ' ' || REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTR(work_request_message.message_text, 1, 10000), '(', ''), ')', '') || ' '  AS "Messages",
        --SUBSTR(work_request_message.message_text, 1, 10000) AS "Messages",
        work_request_status.STATUS As "Status",
        work_request.create_date As "Creation Date"
    FROM work_request
    LEFT JOIN work_request_note ON work_request.WORK_REQUEST_ID = work_request_note.WORK_REQUEST_ID
    LEFT JOIN work_request_message ON work_request.WORK_REQUEST_ID = work_request_message.WORK_REQUEST_ID
    LEFT JOIN work_request_type ON work_request.WORK_REQUEST_TYPE_ID = work_request_type.WORK_REQUEST_TYPE_ID
    LEFT JOIN CMS_USER ON work_request.ASSIGNED_TO_USER_ID = CMS_USER.SEQ_USER_ID
    LEFT JOIN deleted_cms_user ON work_request.ASSIGNED_TO_USER_ID = deleted_cms_user.USER_ID
    LEFT JOIN COMPANY ON work_request.company_id = company.company_id AND company.corp_ID IN ('CB', 'CC')
    LEFT JOIN work_request_status ON work_request.STATUS_ID = work_request_status.STATUS_ID
    WHERE (work_request.corp_ID IN ('CB', 'CC') OR work_request.financial_institution_id = 'CO')
        AND work_request_type.WORK_REQUEST_TYPE_NAME <> 'Client Notification Exception Request'
        AND TRUNC(work_request.create_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/01/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('11/09/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        AND ((work_request.create_date > sysdate-30) AND ( work_request.STATUS_ID = 90))
        OR work_request.STATUS_ID IN (0,10)
),
NotesWithStatus AS (
    SELECT
        "COMPANY NUMBER",
        "COMPANY NAME",
        "Confirmation #",
        "Request Type",
        "Detail Description",
        "Date Submitted",
        "Date Completed",
        "Days to Complete",
        "Assigned To Id",
        "Assigned To NAME",
        "Deleted Assigned To ID",
        "Deleted Assigned To Name",
        "Is Complaint",
        "Results in Complaint",
        --MAX("Messages") AS "Messages", -- Use MAX to include Messages
        LISTAGG("Messages", ' ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORDER BY TO_CHAR("Creation Date", 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DESC) AS "Messages",
        LISTAGG("Notes", ' ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORDER BY TO_CHAR("Creation Date", 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DESC) AS "Notes",
        "Status",
        "Creation Date"
    FROM CombinedNotes
    GROUP BY
        "COMPANY NUMBER",
        "COMPANY NAME",
        "Confirmation #",
        "Request Type",
        "Detail Description",
        "Date Submitted",
        "Date Completed",
        "Days to Complete",
        "Assigned To Id",
        "Assigned To NAME",
        "Deleted Assigned To ID",
        "Deleted Assigned To Name",
        "Is Complaint",
        "Results in Complaint",
        "Status",
        "Creation Date"
)
SELECT
    "COMPANY NUMBER",
    "COMPANY NAME",
    "Confirmation #",
    "Request Type",
    "Detail Description",
    "Date Submitted",
    "Date Completed",
    "Days to Complete",
    "Assigned To Id",
    "Assigned To NAME",
    "Deleted Assigned To ID",
    "Deleted Assigned To Name",
    "Is Complaint",
    "Results in Complaint",
    "Notes",
    "Messages",
    "Status"
FROM NotesWithStatus
ORDER BY TO_CHAR("Creation Date", 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

and i found the values in Notes column in ascending order like this
"10/04/2023 13:27:55 Work Request was assigned to Mary Bang MBCorpCB1  10/04/2023 13:27:57 Work Request was completed by Mary Bang MBCorpCB1  10/11/2023 08:58:59 Work Request was reassigned to Mona Lash f2326COcorp  10/11/2023 08:59:01 Work Request was reset to new by Mona Lash f2326COcorp "

Desired value should in descending like below
"10/11/2023 08:59:01 Work Request was reset to new by Mona Lash f2326COcorp 08:58:59 Work Request was reassigned to Mona Lash f2326COcorp 10/04/2023 13:27:57 Work Request was completed by Mary Bang MBCorpCB1 10/04/2023 13:27:55 Work Request was assigned to Mary Bang MBCorpCB1"

Comment: Do you mean just changing `ORDER BY "Date Submitted"` to `ORDER BY "Date Submitted" DESC` in your listagg calls? (You might want to explore creating a [mre] for future questions - it's hard to see what the issue is when you just present a large query with little relevant context, what seems to be quite a lot of irrelevant code and information, and no data...)

Comment: I updated the script , actually I used ORDER BY ORDER BY TO_CHAR("Creation Date", 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DESC but still not working , either DESC or ASC. its just combining NOTES columns in ASC order

Comment: Don't convert dates to strings before using them to order something (unless in ISO format, and even then it's a pointless step).

Comment: so i simply take "Creation Date"?

Answer (score 1):

Either use ISO8601 formatting for dates `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` (which can be sorted as a string) or pass the date as a date, not a formatted string from the sub-query factoring clause (`WITH` clause).

If you pass strings in the format `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` and you try to sort them then you will be sorting by month then day and then year.

So don't format the dates as string in the sub-query factoring clause, just leave them as dates (and don't concatenate the message and note dates into the text) and then do the formatting later after you have used the date values to order the query:

```sql
WITH CombinedNotes AS (
  SELECT lots_of_columns,
         work_request.CREATE_DATE,    -- Don't format here
         work_request.COMPLETE_DATE,  -- Don't format here
         more_columns,
         work_request_note.create_date AS note_create_date,
                                      -- Don't format or concatenate here
         TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(work_request_note.note_text, 1, 10000), 'A()', 'A')
           AS note_text,
         work_request_message.create_date AS message_create_date,
                                      -- Don't format or concatenate here
         TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(work_request_message.message_text, 1, 10000), 'A()', 'A')
           AS message_text,
         even_more_columns
  FROM   many_tables
)
SELECT lots_of_columns,
       -- Format the dates at the last point you are going to need them for
       -- ordering
       TO_CHAR(create_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "Date Submitted",
       TO_CHAR(create_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "Date Completed",
       more_columns,
       -- Use the date in the ORDER BY and not a formatted string
       LISTAGG(
         TO_CHAR(message_create_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
         || message_text,
         ' ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...'
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY message_create_date DESC) AS "Messages",
       -- Use the date in the ORDER BY and not a formatted string
       LISTAGG(
         TO_CHAR(note_create_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
         || note_text,
         ' ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...'
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY note_create_date DESC) AS "Notes",
         even_more_columns
FROM   CombinedNotes
GROUP BY
       lots_of_columns,
       more_columns,
       even_more_columns
ORDER BY
       -- Use the date in the ORDER BY and not a formatted string
       create_date;
```

Comment: Let me try and comeback to you

Comment: Getting error "[Error] Execution (123: 17): ORA-00904: "Notes": invalid identifier

"

Comment: @Vimal Make sure you use the correct identifiers. The identifiers you use in the sub-query factoring clause (`WITH` clause) are the same ones that are used in the final `SELECT`. My answer defines a `note_text` column in the `WITH` clause and then uses that in the final `SELECT` so if you are using `"Notes" in the final `SELECT` then you are getting the error because the identifier has not been defined.